# Нужна ли запятая перед союзом «да и»?

Tags: запятые, союзы

1. Тыквенный(,) да и грибной(,) суп – это вкусно.
2. Мне нравятся коты(,) да и кошки.
3. Том(,) да и я(,) пошли на вечеринку-тусовку.
4. Я был с моей мамой(,) да и с моим папой тоже.

Comment: 1 и 3 неправильные. Добавление ещё одного элемента в середине фразы не делается.

Comment: У вас, но не у котов.

Comment: В русском языке, ваши коты тоже на нём говорят. Просто в конец переставьте, и будет грамотно.

Comment: Вы слышали такие фразы, как "Ты несёшь какую-то дичь"? Зачем вам, чтобы о ваших предложениях так говорили? Прислушивайтесь.

Comment: Или просто убрать "и".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Вместо вступления**

Союз ***ДА И*** — **интереснейший союз!** В Интернете можно найти **много информации** о нем: Розенталь, Справочник по пунктуации, ссылки на различные учебные материалы (можно посмотреть обзор вариантов https://orfoschool.ru/page_81815/). На нашем форуме он тоже обсуждался.

**Чем интересен этот союз?** Он включает союз  ***ДА***  и усилительное слово ***И*** (союз или частицу), при  этом у самого союза ***ДА*** может быть **три функции.** Вот и считайте, сколько значений получится! И еще **три формы** письма: одна запятая, две запятые, нет запятых.

Можно выделить две основные формы написания для однородного члена с этим союзом: отделяется запятой, обособляется запятыми.

**Решение задачи**

1. *Тыквенный, **да и грибной суп** – это вкусно.*

Здесь выбор: второе определение нельзя  отделить от существительного (обособления нет).

**[У Розенталя пункт 2:](http://old-rozental.ru/punctum_uk.php?pid=69)**

В этом, да и в двух соседних предложениях сказуемое выражено краткой формой прилагательного — нельзя выделить оборот да и в двух соседних, так как нарушится связь между определением и определяемым словом (получится: в этом… предложениях).

2. *Мне нравятся коты, **да и кошки**.*

Нет выбора: однозначное отделение присоединительного члена предложения.

3. *Том, **да и я**,  пошли на вечеринку-тусовку.*

Здесь выбор: обособление однородного члена с  присоединительным значением.

4. *Я был с моей мамой, **да и с моим папой тоже**.*

Нет выбора: однозначное отделение присоединительного члена предложения.

Comment: "Да и" — присоединительный. Где запятая перед "суп"? Такого не может быть. Найдите такое в правилах. В третьем получается "Том пошли", неверная грамматика.

Comment: Не волнуйтесь так, ведите себя интеллигентно.  (1) Правило Розенталя приведено. (3) Согласование сказуемого по смыслу, а не по форме.

Comment: (1) Ерунда. После одного слова перелом конструкции... Звучит очень странно. (2) Согласование по смыслу — когда есть "большинство", "половина" или т.п. Вот это точно бред. Грамматика на двойку...

Comment: (1) Розенталь нехорош? Приведите примеры из литературных текстов или других источников. (2) Две формы согласования для сказуемого – это общий принцип решения для всех случаев.   Кстати, вы можете предложить свои варианты решений, я их не вижу. Один информационный шум

Comment: (1) Не очень хорош. Он одобрил такой перелом конструкции (грамматики). Видимо, тогда такое часто встречалось. Но у него удачные примеры, а у вас какая-то ерунда. Для этого должно быть основание, абсолютно однородные по смыслу элементы не подходят, нет смысла из-за такого делать переход. Короче, тупо. (2) Нет такого в правилах. Никакой нормальный человек так не напишет в книге. Например: *Коля, и Вася тоже, пришли на вечеринку.* Это абсурд. Какой вопрос (абсурдный по двум пунктам), такой и ответ.

Comment: Мои варианты в комментариях — переставить в конец!

Comment: Пусть будет шум, глушит загрязнённый канал...

Comment: Там одни эмоции. Запишите предложения (1) и (3). Или напишите отзыв о них. Коротко и без шума.  Это будет ваше мнение, а мы послушаем другие.

Comment: Уже всё написано (переставить или убрать "и"). Здесь очередное испытывание языка на прочность.

Comment: Сами переставляйте и убирайте, а здесь ответ запишите, как в школе. Ответ: (1); (2).

Comment: Ужас! Пишите сами по моим инструкциям.

Comment: Опять эмоции вместо ответа. Двойка!

Comment: А вам единица!!

Comment: Обменялись любезностями? Пока, пока...